# Pseudorandom Generator returns the same bits every time

Tags: java, random

I am currently trying to generate a 64-bit number represented by bits in a string.

When I have made the string, I use parts of the string to generate stats. However, every time I run the program it returns the same stats, even though it's supposed to be random.

So I did a few checks, and it seems that Seed always comes out as -1. I don't exactly know how to fix this one as I haven't touched coding in quite a while.

Help would be much appreciated ^_^

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    long seed = (long) Math.floor((Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF)); // <-- The issue
    long result = (0x5D588B656C078965L * seed) + 0x0000000000269EC3L;
    String s = Long.toBinaryString(result);
    System.out.println(s + "," + s.length());

    int spdef = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(2, 7), 2);
    int spatk = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(8, 13), 2);
    int speed = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(14, 19), 2);
    int def = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(20, 25), 2);
    int atk = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(26, 31), 2);
    int hp = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(32, 37), 2);

    System.out.println("spdef\tspatk\tspeed\tdef\tatk\thp");
    System.out.println(spdef + "\t" + spatk + "\t" + speed +
            "\t" + def + "\t" + atk + "\t" + hp);
}
```

}

Comment: Why you multiply Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFF ?

Comment: To get a random number between 0 and 0xFFFFFFFF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `0xFFFFFFFF`, but that is an `int` literal, equal to `-1`, so the floor is always `-1`.  Specify a `long` literal instead, with an `L` suffix.  `0xFFFFFFFFL` isn't `-1` as a `long`, it's 2^32 - 1.

```
long seed = (long) Math.floor((Math.random() * 0xFFFFFFFFL));
```

For a couple runs, the seed is:

```
3186506811
1401221963
1537111640
```

Comment: That actually fixed it. Though the string now no longer comes out as 64 in length, though that's not really an issue.

Comment: The floor is _almost_ always -1. It could also be 0. :)  (+1'ed, because that's the least I could do after being so pedantic)